# GraphQL Query List using americanexpress/nodes

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I'm using GraphQL client americanexpress/nodes.

This is the query I want to have:

```
query{
  getLatestData(cppsId: "123", type: "battery", dataCount:2) {
    value
    dateTime
}
```

The server return a list of objects containing the value und the dateTime.
Using Postman, the server sucessfully returns a list.

```
{
"data": {
    "getLatestData": [
        {
            "value": "7823",
            "dateTime": "1564197294"
        },
        {
            "value": "7837",
            "dateTime": "1564196469"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I'm using the following annotated class:

```
@GraphQLProperty(name = "getLatestData", arguments = {
@GraphQLArgument(name = "cppsId"), @GraphQLArgument(name = "type"), @GraphQLArgument(name = "dataCount") })
public class GetLatestDataAnnotationClass {
  private String dateTime;
  private String value;

  public GetLatestDataAnnotationClass() {
  }

 //...
```

and building the request:

```
GraphQLTemplate template = new GraphQLTemplate();

GraphQLRequestEntity requestEntity;
try {
  requestEntity = GraphQLRequestEntity.Builder()
      .url(endpoint)
      .request(GetLatestDataAnnotationClass.class)
      .arguments(new Arguments("getLatestData",
          new Argument<String>("cppsId", cppsId), new Argument<String>("type", type), new Argument<Integer>("dataCount", dataCount)))
      .build();
  GraphQLResponseEntity<GetLatestDataAnnotationClass> responseEntity = template.query(
      requestEntity,
      GetLatestDataAnnotationClass.class);
```

However, the result is a single object of type GetLatestDataAnnotationClass and not the desired List of GetLatestDataAnnotationClass. I tried to work around with nested classes but the result query was something like:

```
query { getLatestData (cppsId:"123",type:"battery",dataCount:2) {
    abcd { value dateTime }
    } 
}
```

where abcd is the list containing GetLatestDataAnnotationClass objects. Is there any annotation I'm missing? How can I tell the client to parse a List instead of just a single instance of the class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the request class like this to get it properly serializing.

```
public class LatestDataRequest {
  @GraphQLArguments({
    @GraphQLArgument(name = "cppsId"),
    @GraphQLArgument(name = "type"),
    @GraphQLArgument(name = "dataCount")
  })
  private List<DataValue> getLatestData;
  ...
}
```

+

```
public class DataValue {
  private String dateTime;
  private String value;
  ...
}
```

then building the request looks like

```
GraphQLTemplate template = new GraphQLTemplate();

GraphQLRequestEntity requestEntity;
try {
  requestEntity = GraphQLRequestEntity.Builder()
      .url(endpoint)
      .request(LatestDataRequest.class)
      .arguments(new Arguments("getLatestData",
        new Argument<String>("cppsId", cppsId),
        new Argument<String>("type", type),
        new Argument<Integer>("dataCount", dataCount)))
      .build();
  GraphQLResponseEntity<LatestDataRequest> responseEntity = template.query(requestEntity, LatestDataRequest.class);
```